# Is there a way to use variable as the key in jsoncpp?

Tags: c++, c++17, jsoncpp

I wrote a function to save directory structure to json file.I'm using Jsoncpp libary to encode json.And I'm using c++17.But it throws a `Json::LogicError`. It says that "`Json::Value::operator[](ArrayIndex)` requires arrayValue".Here is the function:

```cpp
void ScanFolder(string path)
{
        CTYPE::PFILELIST pfl;
        pfl=CTYPE::to(DIRVIEW::LoadDir(path));
        JSONFILE::Encode(DIRVIEW::AddPath(path,"fconfig.json"),pfl);
        for(const auto&ele : pfl.data)
                if(ele.type=="Folder")
                        ScanFolder(DIRVIEW::AddPath(pfl.current,ele.filename));
        return;
}
```

`CTYPE`,`DIRVIEW` and `JSONFILE` is namespaces defined by me.Here are the `Encode` function:

```cpp
namespace JSONFILE
{
    void Encode(string filepath,CTYPE::PFILELIST data)
    {
        Json::StyledWriter writer;
        Json::Value arr,obj;
        fstream out;
        arr["Current_Folder"]=data.current;
        int i=0;
        for(const auto&ele : data.data)
        {
            arr["Files"][i]=ele.filename;
            obj["Type"]=ele.type;
            obj["Icon"]=ele.icon;
            arr[ele.filename]=obj;
            i++;
        }
        string jsonstr=writer.write(arr);
        out.open(filepath.c_str(),ios::binary|ios::out|ios::trunc);
        if(out.is_open())
            out<<jsonstr<<endl;
        else
            return;
        return;
    }
};
```

I found that the code witch caused the error is `arr[ele.filename]=obj;`.When I deleted it,the code works.I have checked the value of `ele.filename`,it isn't a empty variable and it have right value like 'filename.txt'.So what should I do to fix it?

Comment: When the exception is thrown, what is the value of `ele.filename`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Almost all of the code you pasted isn't relevant to the problem that you're describing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's what it says - you're trying to perform array indexing on something that is not an array.

When you write `arr["Files"]`, and `arr` is a `Json::Value`, [a null object with that key is created for you](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#acb912f4ec40a25ea6eb387730885f3d9):

> Access an object value by name, create a null member if it does not exist.

So now you have a `Json::Value` called `arr["Files"]`, which has the "null" type.

But your next step was to treat it as an array, in `arr["Files"][i]`. That doesn't work; [an array is not created for you](http://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#a7d99f5dba388cdaa152ce6ef933d64ef):

> Access an array element (zero based index ).
>
> If the array contains less than index element, then null value are inserted in the array so that its size is index+1. (You may need to say 'value[0u]' to get your compiler to distinguish this from the operator[] which takes a string.)

*(Notice that this talks about auto-inserting elements, but not auto-creating the array itself.)*

---

This is really easy to fix; just make that object be an array:

```
// ** New line here: **
arr["Files"] = Json::Value(Json::arrayValue);

for (const auto& ele : data.data)
{
    arr["Files"][i] = ele.filename;
    obj["Type"] = ele.type;
    obj["Icon"] = ele.icon;
    arr[ele.filename] = obj;
    i++;
}
```

---

Here's what a minimal testcase for this issue looks like:

```
#include <json/value.h>

int main()
{
    Json::Value val;
    val[0] = "foo";   // This throws Json::LogicError
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.But it still throw the same error.My debug result says that ```arr[ele.filename]=obj;``` is causing the error,when I deleted it,the error was gone.

Comment: And I have checked the value of ```ele.filename```,it isn't a empty variable and it have right value like 'filename.txt'.

Comment: What is `ele.filename`?

Comment: It's file or folder name.For example,filename.txt

Comment: I know what is the program now.There is a folder named "Files" in the folded I want to scan,if I changed its name,the error was gone.

Comment: @ObjectUnknown I know what "filename" means. I'm asking what `ele.filename` is. What is its type? What is its value when the exception is thrown? The actual value, not an example.

Comment: @ObjectUnknown Empty keys are permitted in JSON, and (as far as I can tell) by JsonCpp, so altering the filesystem should have had no effect. Are you sure you didn't change something else?